# How can I throttle incoming packets for a specific program in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, qos, packet, throttling, rate-limits

I want to throttle incoming connections for GTAV.exe. My router doesn't support QoS so I'm looking for a way to limit the incoming packets through software.

I have tried creating a QoS policy through gpedit.msc but this only allows limiting outbound traffic.

I am on Windows 10 pro if it matters.

**Edit**

If it's not possible to throttle an applications incoming traffic, a sytem-wide incoming traffic throttle would suffice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a program called [NetBalancer](https://netbalancer.com/) which allowed me to set the upload speed.